# New Let'sencrypt certificate ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Ubuntu 20.04
Nginx

I obtained a certificate with certbot like sudo certbot --nginx -d pvapp-2021.umwelt-campus.de. And included the paths to the certificate to my two nginx config files (one for the frontend and one as reverse proxy for node) like:

```
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pvapp-2021.umwelt-campus.de/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pvapp-2021.umwelt-campus.de/privkey.pem;

 include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
```

When now making requests to my backend (e.g. logging in) I get the error:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID tho the certificate definitely is valid.`

Do I need a extra certificate for my backend? If yes, how would I do this? What else could cause the error?

Also `sudo certbot renew --dry-run` fails.

My nginx node conf: (ssl part)

```
server {
     listen       443 ssl;
     listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
     server_name  pvapp-2021.umwelt-campus.de;

     # point to ssl certificate path
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pvapp-2021.umwelt-campus.de/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pvapp-2021.umwelt-campus.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

     include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

     root /var/www/client/pvapp-client/dist;
     error_page 404 =200 /index.html;

     location /backend {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:60702;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
          proxy_ssl_verify off;
     }
```

Appreciate all help.

Comment: Is the date/time/timezone actually valid on the machine throwing the error?

Comment: @RyanBolger Yes, it's totally fine.

Comment: So, you have a reverse proxy, a frontend and a backend... are all three on different servers ? do you use TLS on all three connections ? which connection had the error, and where did the error come up exactly ? could you explain? Or is this the error message seen in your browser ?

Comment: @martin They are all on the same server. The proxy exists to handle SSL for the backend so it can run on http. The error occurs as soon as I make requests to the backend (login, etc.)
And that's exactly the error message seen in chrome.

Comment: ah okay... no, you do not need a seperate certificate for your backend. Could you expand the error message in chrome and show us what it written in the details of the error message ?

Comment: @Martin There's nothing to expand. It's just this one line. Somehow firefox shows me a cors error, but that makes no sense to me.

Comment: according to this page, there should be something to expand... but I don't have chrome installed to test it. https://comodosslstore.com/resources/how-to-fix-net-err_cert_date_invalid-error-on-google-chrome/

Comment: I figured it out - on my firefox, when opening the page https://pvapp.umwelt-campus.de/backend/user/login, I receive an expired certificate warning, which tells me that the certificate expired on 25/02/2021 .  You probably forgot to restart a nginx server after renewing the letsencrypt certificate...

Comment: @martin You know what? You're not totally wrong. But it was way more dumb. I just forgot to change my axios api to route to the correct backend! It was still on my dev-server. 
But thanks anyways! Your comment would've made me guess that too. If you just write an answer with that I can accept it.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saying is that you should "trust the error message". It's telling you that `net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID` which means that somewhere, there's a certificate that it's refusing to use because it either has expired, or is believed to have expired.

- If it actually has expired, it may be an old leftover certificate from before.
- If it's only *believed* to have expired, the time settings on the client making the request is probably wrong.

You can start by checking the expiry of the pem files that the config is told to use:

```
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/pvapp-2021.umwelt-campus.de/fullchain.pem
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/pvapp-2021.umwelt-campus.de/privkey.pem
```

If they are fine, check the time settings (and provide output) both on your server and the requesting client with something like `timedatectl`.

Also, your configuration is not complete: you're doing  `include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;` but you haven't shown what this file contains. It's quite possible it contains another certificate, loaded after the ones mentioned above, that overrides the settings and loads an old certificate instead.